# How to check if element has empty class?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem how to check if an element has empty class. I tried the code below, but doesn't work.

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="">
   <ul>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> references</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i> about me</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i> abilities</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>


 if ($('#main-nav:not([class])')){

        $(this).addClass("nav-type1");

 }
```

Comment: Define 'not working'

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: So your conditions isn't evaluating as desired. Debug.

Comment: mm i supposed that it will add class to nav but it didnt

Comment: `this` inside the `if` is the `window` object... also IDs are unique

Comment: ou man thank you very much : ))

Comment: And, enclose your javascript into `<script>` tags, or it will be interpreted as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merely do this:

```
var $elem = $('#main-nav');
if (!$elem.attr('class')) {
    $elem.addClass('nav-type1');
}
```

where I think that comments are not necessary...

Answer (score 0):

You could either use hasClass with an empty string or try toggleClass

```
 if ($('#main-nav').hasClass("")){

    $(this).addClass("nav-type1");
```

}

OR:

```
$('main-nav').toggleClass("nav-type1");
```